# How to push items from an array to another array using ramda expressions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, ramda.js

I have a small problem, I have an array of children, I parse it, I get data from it and reformat it and push it into another array `subMenuContent`, it is working fine, but I need to clean my code a little bit better, I am using ramda as a library to simplify things for me.

Here is what I was doing before, simple javascript.

```
    let subMenuContent = [];

    for (let counter = 0; counter < children.length; counter++) {
      let parent = children[counter].props.item.id;
      let childs = children[counter].props.item.childrens;
      for (let i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
        let child = {
          content: childs[i],
          class: 'cdiscountLinks cdiscountChip-' + childs[i].id + '-' + parent,
        };
        subMenuContent.push(child);
      }
    }
```

What I am trying to do now is :

```
    const subMenuContents = map(function(item){
      let parent = item.props.item.id;
      let childs = item.props.item.childrens;
      const itemChilds = map(function(child){
        let childItem = {
          content: child,
          class: 'cdiscountLinks cdiscountChip-' + child.id + '-' + parent,
        }
        return childItem;
      }, childs)
      return itemChilds;

    },children)
```

EDIT : Now I used this

```
    const subMenuContents = pipe(
      map(function(item) {
        let parent = item.props.item.id;
        let childs = item.props.item.childrens;
        const itemChilds = map(function(child) {
          let childItem = {
            content: child,
            class: 'cdiscountLinks cdiscountChip-' + child.id + '-' + parent,
          };
          return childItem;
        }, childs);
        return itemChilds;
      }, children),
      flatten,
    )(subMenuContents);
```

But I get an error :

```
f.apply is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could share some simplified input data and the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in looking at the [`R.chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) function in Ramda. This is sometimes known as `flatMap`, because it can be thought of mapping over the data type and then flattening the nested result.

`R.chain` can work with many different data types, though for arrays it effectively maps over each element of the array to produce an array for each then concatenates them all together.

In your example, you will want to look at replacing your outermost `const subMenuContents = map(...)` with `const subMenuContents = chain(...)`.

Comment: I used the flatten ramda function, according to the documentation it does what I am looking for, but I got an error, can you check my update ?

Comment: If you're using `R.pipe` then you'll only want to partially apply the first function (i.e. don't feed it the `children` yet). Then where you currently are passing `subMenuContents` as an argument, you'll want to replace with `children` instead.

Comment: Or if you're not planning on reusing `subMenuContents` as a function, you can remove the use of `pipe` with `flatten(map(function(item) { ... }, children))`, or more succinctly as `chain(function(item) { ... }, children)`.